# Laptop's Intel GPU - Screen is scrambled (sometimes), what to do?

Tags: laptop, gpu

I have a Lenovo T500, and my applications are scrambled sometimes (with the Intel GPU). Is there a way to fix this, or the GPU is dying?

Tried downloading a new MHD4500 driver from the Intel website, it said: I should contact the vendor. Sure I did, I downloaded the System Update software from Lenovo. But it doesn't show any new drivers available for the Intel GPU.

(It's got an Intel MHD4500 (integrated) and an ATI 3650M (discrete) GPU.)

[image: Spicing up the default and boring look of HWiNFO with some hardcore effects.]

[image: Awesome skin for Chrome, sponsored by Intel]

[image: Explorer's top bar with some cool colors]

**When I do a restart, I get no problems for a while or at all. Is it heat, that kills the GPU's normal drawing?:**

[image]

[image]

**I tried running Furmark, to make some heat (only wanted to run it for a very short time, like 10-20 seconds), but I get an error message.**

[image]

Comment: The PC is quite cold, and I didn't run anything CPU/GPU intensive lately. Though, I used the ATI card recently, because the laptop was plugged in. Now I just want less noise and heat.

Comment: Do you see this condition outside of windows, like on the BIOS loading, or windows loading screens?

Comment: No, and I think I found the solution. So far, so good.

Comment: I was wrong, removed the wrong answer. I thought F.lux caused the problem. But after removing it, I still get the scrambled windows and stuff.

Comment: @zackrspv - Only in Windows. (yet?)

Comment: The reason I ask if this exists OUTSIDE of windows, is because if there is heat damage to the actual video adapter, this type of issue is common, even if the current heat levels are low.  Once the damage is done, it's not fixable (at least not directly).  However, if it's only in windows, I would try to boot your PC in VGA mode only, and see if the corruption is still there.  Always good to rule out the driver, before ruling out the hardware.

Comment: So I should go into the BIOS and start opening menus, etc. Btw the driver is unchanged, I've always been using this one. I only used the Intel card when I had to travel (battery time), and only updated the ATI driver.

Comment: David Schwartz's answer below is where I was going with this line of conversation.  I would contact your computer manufacturer.

Comment: Well, I can contact them, but all they will ask is the hourly price, and a replacement motherboard (which costs A LOT). So ... I'll use the ATI card until then, and if that dies too... I'll try to search for a replacement from eBay or a used t500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical of connection problems between the GPU and the motherboard. Repeated heating and cooling cycles cause the connections between the motherboard and the die in the GPU to crack (usually in what's called the "bump underfill"). Often, at least at first, things get better when the GPU is hot because the thermal expansion causes the cracks to fill. Over time, the cracks get bad enough that the GPU becomes unusable.